# Building Service Fabric applications takes a lot of time

Tags: service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-stateless, service-fabric-actor

Building a Service Fabric application with around 3 services and 4 actors, it is very slow. It builds with normal speed until it gets to the Service Fabric project and then stays for more than 5 minutes until it finishes to build the project. And packaging also takes around 5 minutes.

At first I thought it is Resharper that was slowing down so I uninstalled it, is only marginally faster...

My PC it's quite a quick one (Intel Core i7, 32GB RAM, Samsung SSD), other project types it is fast.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on various parameters like PartitionCount, MinReplicaSetSize and TargetReplicaSetSize. for example, if MinReplicaSetSize is 3 and PartitionCount is 10 then for each actor or service 10*3 = 30 replicas and in your case, total services are 7.

hence you'll have 210 replicas. so it takes some time even if your machine has a good configuration.

You can edit those parameters value in Service fabric's ApplicationManifest.xml